# Как правильно динамически менять границы minDate и maxDate в datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Здравствуйте.

у меня есть 2 datetimepicker на форме с и по

определяю их при document.create так

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#datetime_from').datetimepicker(
            {
                maxDate: tdatetime,
                onSelect: function(selected,evnt) {
                    updateDateTime_from(selected);
                }
            }
        ).datetimepicker("setDate", fdatetime);

        $('#datetime_to').datetimepicker(
            {
                minDate: fdatetime,
                onSelect: function(selected,evnt) {
                    updateDateTime_to(selected);
                }
            }
        ).datetimepicker("setDate", tdatetime);
});
```

вне определяю updateDateTime_from, updateDateTime_to
для того, чтобы обрабатывать смену выбора даты и времени в них пытаюсь корректировать опции minDate и maxDate

```
function updateDateTime_from(value){
$("#datetime_to").datetimepicker("option", "minDate", value);
};
function updateDateTime_to(value){
$("#datetime_from").datetimepicker("option", "maxDate", value);
};
```

по факту в value динамически передача проходит корректно, НО смена minDate и maxDate не происходит....

В чем ошибка и как ее решить?

сделал макет https://jsfiddle.net/drno/ahvLcexq/

меняю время в datetime_from - С

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

minData в datetime_to меняется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

НО должно сдвинуться поле выбора минимального времени и даты в datetime_to - ПО, но оно не сдвигается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

День добрый!

Если честно, не до конца разобрался в том что именно происходит, но две вещи могу сказать точно:

1. Обновление (refresh) вам никак не поможет решить проблему
2. Проблема в том что вы присваиваете значение которое этот элемент
   управления (DateTimePicker) не понимает

Решение в том чтобы присвоить mindate или maxdate в [формате javascript Date](https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime) который есть зло страшное ибо разные браузеры обрабатывают его по разному.

В итоге можно ручками разобрать вашу переменную  value или не терять время и  обратиться к библиотеке которая сделает это за вас. Я очень [рекомендую библиотеку momentJS](https://momentjs.com/) которая прекрасно переваривает разные браузеры.

вот что нужно сделать

```
function updateDateTime_from(value) {
      //value -> трансформировать в объект javascript Date

      $("#datetime_to").datetimepicker("option", "minDate", ВАШ_ОБЪЕКТ);
      //$("#datetime_to").datetimepicker("refresh");
    };
```

с помощью MomentJS это решается так:

```
var rr = moment(value, "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"); //rr это ОБЪЕКТ_МОМЕНТ
$("#datetime_to").datetimepicker("option", "minDate", rr.toDate()); //rr.toDate() это ВАШ_ОБЪЕКТ - javascript Date
```

Ваш код работающий как описано выше (немного отформатировал для себя).

https://jsfiddle.net/pvkovalev/2eq01b28/

Опять же, я немного не разобрался но на вид все работает.
Недеюсь поможет. Удачи

## ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ 2017-08-21 22:07

Итак, альтернативное решение на основе компонента который мне выдал поисковик  bootstrap-datetimepicker который тут http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Он тянет с собой не мало библиотек и устанавливается в таком порядке:

1. jQuery
2. Moment.js
3. Bootstrap.js
4. Bootstrap Datepicker script
5. Bootstrap CSS
6. Bootstrap Datepicker CSS
7. Locales for Moment's

[подробнее тут](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#installation-guides)

Далее копируем пример и подправляем немного код:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'ru',
    minDate: moment('21.08.2017 08:23', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm'),
    maxDate: moment('21.08.2017 14:53', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm')
});
});
```

Вроде бы работает как надо.

[Полностью работающий пример можно глянуть тут](https://jsfiddle.net/pvkovalev/735kf86d/)

Других вариантов у меня нет  Надеюсь этот вам поможет. Удачи

Comment: благодарю за внимание к моему вопросу, НО мое ожидание в решении этой проблемы сдедующее: в пикере С я изменяю время в прошлое например и в пикере ПО минимальное время и дата сдвигаются в прошлое, сейчас меняется только дата, а время не двигается, если мы работаем в рамках одних суток в пикере С и ПО. Надеюсь я смог объяснить свою боль...

Comment: @NikolayBaranenko в описании контрола говорится только про дату, но не про время i.e. The minimum selectable date.  К сожалению не могу найти примера про время.

Comment: @NikolayBaranenko вот тут тоже смотрите: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max речь идёт только о датах, но не о времени. Так что эту часть нужно проверять видимо вручную или другой элемент управления. Может быть дату задавать этим элементом, а время другим? Ну или кто-то может работал, подскажет.

Comment: pvkovalev, мне хотелось чтобы на форме появился datetimepicker причем нормально воспроизводящийся как в Chrome так и в Explorer, по ходу реализации возникло желание регулировать автоматически min и max Date. Может быть в этой реализации такой функции и нет. Готов рассмотреть другие варианты с которыми есть уверенность, что такая задача решается.

Comment: @NikolayBaranenko я обновил свой ответ - добавил пример на основе другого компонента (бесплатного) - если не подойдёт - не серчайте, у меня тут уже ночь 